# IsManipulationEnabled = true prevents touch closing ComboBox

Tags: .net, wpf, combobox, popup, touch

We encounter an issue with touch events using a `ComboBox` and a control with the `IsManipulationEnabled` property set to `true`.

Here is a simple sample which illustrates it:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ComboBox Grid.Row="0">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 1"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 2"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 3"/>
        </ComboBox>

        <Border Grid.Row="1"
                IsManipulationEnabled="True"
                Background="Red"/>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

If you click on the `ComboBox`, the `ComboBox`'s `Popup` opens. Then if you click on the red `Border` (only with touch on a tablet), the `Popup` does not close. If you click on the red `Border` with a stylus or a mouse, the `Popup` closes.

Using [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), you can see the following behavior when the `Popup` is open and you click on the red `Border`:

With touch and `IsManipulationEnabled="True"`:

```
PreviewTouchDown on MainWindow (Handled = false)
TouchDown on Border (Handled = false)
PreviewTouchUp on MainWindow (Handled = false)
TouchUp on Border (Handled = false)
```

With touch and `IsManipulationEnabled="False"`:

```
PreviewTouchDown on MainWindow (Handled = false)
TouchDown on Border (Handled = false)
PreviewMouseDown on MainWindow (Handled = false)
MouseDown on ComboBox (Handled = true)
PreviewTouchUp on MainWindow (Handled = false)
TouchUp on Border (Handled = false)
MouseUp on Border (Handled = false)
```

I understand that setting `IsManipulationEnabled` to `true` implies that the mouse events are no longer raised, that the `ComboBox` cannot capture them and cannot close its `Popup` when a `TouchDown` event is raised.

**So my question is, is there a clean walkaround to force the `ComboBox` to close when it losts focus?**

I know I can catch the `TouchDown` event of the border to explicitly close the `Popup` but I'm looking for a generic solution where the `ComboBox` and the control don't know each other (like overriding the `ComboBox` or the control, create a `Behavior`, an attached property, etc.).